# Simple GUI buttons and inputs

Tags: python, codeskulptor

I am currently in an intro cs class and have a question about simple GUI and more specifically how to take a number (ex 6,7,8) input and when a button is pressed take the input number and determine if it is even or odd so far below is what I have and I get the error message that states: "button_handler() takes exactly 1 arguments (0 given)" Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

```
import simplegui
global text_input

frame = simplegui.create_frame('Testing', 250, 250)
label = frame.add_label('Divisable by 6?')

def input_handler(text_input):
    print "You entered,", text_input

def button_handler(num):
    if float(num) / 6 == 0:
        print "divisable by six"
    else:
        print "Not divisable by 6"


button1 = frame.add_button('divisable by 6?', button_handler)
inp = frame.add_input('Please insert number', input_handler, 50)

frame.start()
```

(BTW the formatting is weird when copied and pasted from code skulptor)

Answer (score 1):

I am familiar with with tkinter and have not used simplegui, but from the error message, I can guess the problem.

`button_handler` is a callback that is called *without any arguments* when the button is clicked.  But you define it with a parameter `number`.  You have to re-write `button_handler to get the number from the input some other way.  I know how to do that with tkinter, but not for simplegui.  Perhaps`input_handler`should write a global that`button_handler` can access.

Answer (score 0):

In this line here:

```
button1 = frame.add_button('divisable by 6?', button_handler)
```

you are not feeding anything to button_handler.  In other words, it has no arguments.  But elsewhere in your code you mandate that button_handler has exactly one argument.  So, you need to update your reference to button_handler in the line above to account for that fact.

(That's the fundamental bit, anyway: I don't want to comment on the rest of your code, since you say it is under construction.)

Answer (score 0):

From the CodeSculptor [documentation](http://www.codeskulptor.org/docs.html#frame-add_button) for `frame.add_button()`:

> The handler should be defined with no parameters

You can grab the content of an input field with `get_text()`. Here is a simple example that prints the content of an input field when a button is pressed:

```
import simplegui

def input_handler(text_input):
    pass

def button_handler():
    print inp.get_text()

frame = simplegui.create_frame("Demonstration of input and button", 300, 300) 
inp = frame.add_input("Input:", input_handler, 100)
frame.add_button("Print", button_handler, 100)
frame.start()
```